# How to get caller function name from durable function orchestrator?

Tags: azure-functions

I have a timer trigger that calls an orchestrator using a durable client. Is there a way of getting the caller function name from within the orchestrator?

```cs
[FunctionName("Starter")]
public static async Task Starter(
    [TimerTrigger("0 0 1 * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo myTimer,
    [DurableClient] IDurableClient starter,
    ILogger log)
{
    await starter.StartNewAsync("Orchestrator", null);
}

[FunctionName("Orchestrator")]
public static async Task Orchestrator(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    // get caller function name here (Starter, in this example)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just pass an argument to the orchestrator:

```
[FunctionName("Starter")]
public static async Task Starter(
    [TimerTrigger("0 0 1 * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo myTimer,
    [DurableClient] IDurableClient starter,
    ILogger log)
{
    await starter.StartNewAsync("Orchestrator", "NAME_OF_THE_CALLER");
}

[FunctionName("Orchestrator")]
public static async Task Orchestrator(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    // get caller function name here (Starter, in this example)
    string caller = context.GetInput<string>();
}
```

Comment: That is what I am doing, but since I have a somewhat complex input on the orchestrator I was wondering if there is an easier way of doing so. Thank you

Comment: you can pass an object rather than string.